# Polymer CLI - npm error code 1

Tags: node.js, polymer

I get this error when trying to install polymer CLI. I keep on getting this whenever i try to install it.

```
sudo npm install --unsafe-perm -g polymer-cli
Password:
npm WARN deprecated bower@1.8.0: ..psst! While Bower is maintained, we 
recommend Yarn and Webpack for *new* front-end projects! Yarn's 
advantage is security and reliability, and Webpack's is support for 
both CommonJS and AMD projects. Currently there's no migration path but 
we hope you'll help us figure out one.
npm WARN deprecated @types/assert@0.0.29: See 
https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/12826
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! Command failed: /usr/bin/git clone --depth=1 -q -b master 
git://github.com/polymerelements/test-fixture.git 
/Users/litsonthomas/.npm/_cacache/tmp/git-clone-eddd277b
npm ERR! /Users/litsonthomas/.npm/_cacache/tmp/git-clone-eddd277b/.git: 
Permission denied
npm ERR! 

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/litsonthomas/.npm/_logs/2017-06-22T17_39_34_600Z-
debug.log
```

I am new to polymer and I don't know where am getting wrong!

Comment: Can you specify your version of npm?

Comment: npm version is 5.0.3

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a pertinent issue in this package (issues in the repository: [#784](https://github.com/Polymer/polymer-cli/issues/784#issuecomment-306091051) [#800](https://github.com/Polymer/polymer-cli/issues/800)). You have to go to the npm site on [Fixing npm Permissions](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions) and follow the steps there.

> You may receive an **EACCES** error when you try to install a package globally. This indicates that you do not have permission to write to the directories that npm uses to store global packages and commands.
>
> You can fix this problem using one of three options:
>
> 1. Change the permission to npm's default directory.
> 2. Change npm's default directory to another directory.
> 3. Install node with a package manager that takes care of this for you.

Whether you should follow one of the three options depends on each particular case. What I would recommend first is to try changing the npm default directory to some place with user read/write permissions. Then, you should start doing `npm i -g` without `sudo`.